# Three phase short circuit and line to ground short circuit

Tags: power, short-circuit, three-phase, fault, single-phase

Why is three phase short circuit calculated current higher than line to ground or (phase to ground) short circuit calculated current in most cases?

Answer (score 2):

Because a line to line voltage is  \$\sqrt{3}\$ higher than line to ground voltage.